# Right associativity for `std::views`

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

Left associativity is already guaranteed by C++ core semantics:
`R|V1|V2` is parsed as `(R|V1)|V2)`. What if the coder wants to explicitly change the order of operations to `R|(V1|V2)`?
Is this possible under C++23?
The reason behind the question is that it simplifies defining custom range adapters:

```
auto myV=V1|V2|V3;
for(auto& x:R1|myV)/*..*/;
for(auto& x:R2|myV)/*..*/;
```

All this needs seems to be a properly constraint overload on `std::views::operator|`;
Does such overload exist?
If not, will it be added?
If not, what's the rationale behind it?

Comment: Unfortunately associativity of C++ operators cannot be changed, overloaded or not.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , you misunderstood. I want to costumize range adapters by composition through chaining the pipe operator. And it is possible. I am asking if the standard has this feature or not?

Comment: I don't believe I misunderstand. The first paragraph is pretty clear: can associativity of the `|` operator be changed? Nope.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No! That's your miss-interpretation. We need a right associativity on view adapters (if you know math as much as you know C++), and it just needs another overload of `operator|`. No changes to the core, just a library tweak.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I bet you didn't look at the snippet right below the 1st paragraph.

Comment: I don't... understand the question, are you asking if `R | (V1 | V2)` is valid?

Comment: @Barry, bingo! You did understand it indeed. I am sure you do have the answer. So please leave a full reply.

Comment: @Barry feel free to suggest a proper edit. I am much better at C++ than English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What if the coder wants to explicitly change the order of operations to `R|(V1|V2)`?

Then they can just write that. That is a valid expression.

The way that [range adaptor closure objects](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptor.object) are defined, there are two equivalences (`C` and `D` here are range adaptor closure objects and `R` is a range):

- `R | C` is equivalent to `C(R)`
- `R | (C | D)` is equivalent to `R | C | D`

The latter is the property that lets you write what you're asking about. For instance:

```cpp
auto flat_map = [](auto f){
    return views::transform(f) | views::join;
};

vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
auto w = v | flat_map([](int i){ return vector<int>(i, i); }
```

And here `w` becomes the range `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`.

Comment: That's great. So composition of adapters is just that simple for an average programmer. All that coder needs is considering the lifetime of parameters to specific adapters.